# Proof verification.Limit of sequence by definition.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that $lim_{n\to\infty}  {q^n} =0$ if $|q|<1$.
I need prove that:
$$(\forall \epsilon >0 )(\exists n_0=n_0(\epsilon))(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})(n\geq n_0 \implies |q^n|<\epsilon)$$
Let $\epsilon >0$ arbitrarily.
$$|q^n|=|q|^n< \epsilon$$
Now use logarithm with base $|q|$ and choose $n_0> log_{|q|}\epsilon$.
I think that this is correct but in books they use some  inequality and i understand their proof also but i only need verification of my solution.

Comment: You need to prove there exists such a $n_0$.  In your proof, you use this fact, but this is what you need to prove!

Comment: can i just use Archimedes principle and choose $n_0 = [log_{|q|}\epsilon]+1$

Comment: You can do it without $\log$: for positive $q$ we have $q=1-h,0<h\le 0$ and use Bernoulli inequality

Comment: Holo ,i know that but i'm interested is my solution good

Comment: How did you define $\log$?

Comment: $log_{a} b$ is number $c$ which satisfy equality $ a^c=b$

Comment: So you need to prove that $\log_{|q|}\epsilon$ exists for all positive $\epsilon$ first